# How to send ECS DesiredCount as a metric to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

Amazon ECS provides following metrics within AWS/ECS namespace:

- CPUReservation,
- CPUUtilization,
- MemoryReservation,
- MemoryUtilization

But for our application, we want to send the "DesiredCount" of an ECS service as a custom metric to CloudWatch.

How can it be achieved?

I know it is not exactly a programming question, but I am not sure where else can I ask this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of getting this value into CloudWatch, you'll have to read the value and publish to CloudWatch yourself.

One way to do that would be to write an AWS Lambda function that will call ECS DescribeServices API and get the `desiredCount` for your service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeServices.html

You can then have your function publish this value to CloudWatch using PutMetricData API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html

Have the lambda function triggered by CloudWatch Events cron rule every minute and you got your metric.